# Can I render the same block twice on a page?

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I want to have `<?php print render ($page['homepage_video'])?>` two different places on the page. By default it can only be done once, but is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what @Chapabu said doesnt work for you, if you have *any* hand-coded module on your site you can use [hook_page_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) to copy the render array information for the block in question and set it into another region of the page.

This is more of a 1-off solution. But, I try to stay away from extra modules todo 1 thing on a site. Especially if you're somewhat comfortable coding a solution.

Here is a small example using [hook_page_build](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) (which runs at the beginning of page builds, hook page_alter runs at the end):

```
/**
 * implementation of hook_page_build().
 *
 * Depending on the path or NID or whatever, we want to
 * embed additional blocks and stuff into the page.
 *
 * I could use Context or the BlocksUI for this but I
 * give clients "Basic Page" for all of these urls and I'm
 * merely appending additional data on those pages.
 */
function ccs_core_page_build(&$page) {
  _page_build_section_header_image($page);
  _page_build_embed_course_views($page);
  _page_build_embed_faculty_views($page);
  _page_build_embed_distinguished_alumni_view($page);
}

function _page_build_embed_distinguished_alumni_view(&$page) {
  if (drupal_get_path_alias() == 'people-contacts/distinguished-alumni') {
    $view = views_get_view('distinguished_alumni_listing');
    $display = 'blocks';
    $view->set_display($display);
    $output = $view->preview($display);
  }
  if (isset($output)) {
    $page['content']['system_main']['distinguished_alumni_listing_view'] = array(
        '#weight' => 99,
        '#markup' => $output,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have this working for a view, but not the block that invokes the view (showing multiple of each view)

Comment: You can load a block programmatically in Drupal 7 ... you should be able todo essentially the same thing using a fetched block content ... I dont have any such code just laying around.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy $page['homepage_video'] variable before it will be rendered and then render both.

```
<?php $homepage_video = $page['homepage_video']; ?>
<?php print render ($page['homepage_video'])?>
<?php print render ($homepage_video)?>
```

Comment: Yeah, that works fine, or just copy the line `<?php print render ($page['homepage_video'])?>` and use it anywhere you want that content.  You could, technically, double print regions too if that makes sense.. `<?php if (!empty($page['homepage_video'])): ?>
                <?php print render($page['homepage_video']); ?>
              <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

[Multiblock](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock) should be able to help, however I've not used it in templates, only through the UI (with Context).

> Drupal's block module is limited by the fact that a block can only
>   have one instance. Each block has a 1:1 relationship with its region,
>   weight, visibility (and other) settings. This means that it is
>   impossible to have blocks in multiple regions or to have blocks that
>   have different settings on different pages. MultiBlock module solves
>   this problem by allowing you to create multiple Block Instances of
>   already existing blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try display Suite Module and place your block in a block field with a different name then place it in the desired region..